# installing libraries in visual studio 2013 python tools

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, wxpython, ptvs

I have visual studio professional 2013 with python tools, and I want to import wxPython library to my code.
how do I install the library on visual studio?

Comment: Would just try to do a normal wxPython install - i.e. download the exe installer which corresponds to the Python version you are using.  I use WingIDE and it didn't need anything special to use wxPython in the code, however it has some helpers to have code completion working for wxPython stuff.

Comment: I do not know if/which Python gets installed by default if you use VS/Python Tools. If it is IronPython, you will not be able to run wxPython (requires CPython instead).

Comment: I use CPython and I did install wxPython on the normal python, but it still doesn't let me import it

Comment: You can check the following: Did you select `Make this the default wxPython` in the installer? Are both wxPython and CPython 32 bit or 64 bit (for practical purposes you can always use the 32-bit versions, even if you are on a 64 bit system without performance penalty). Is there more than one python on the system and did it get installed into the other one?

Comment: I actually didn't select Make this the default wxPython, I didn't know what it means...
I've reinstalled wxpython now and it works fine, Thanks!

Comment: For a detailed explanation see [Link](http://wiki.wxpython.org/MultiVersionInstalls). In a nutshell: If you did not instruct the installer to make this install the default wxPython, you have to import wxversion first and select the installed version.